# Why does Outlook encoding show a ":)" emoji as a "J" in preview?

Tags: encoding, outlook, character-encoding

In email preview, Outlook shows a ":)" emoji as "Thank you J" [image: email preview]

whereas in the normal email view, it is correctly shown as "Thank you " [image: email view]

It being an HTML email, I would expect it to show something like `&#12345` as the emoji substitute, and not a J.

Anyone who has an idea why that could be?

Comment: I do not understand the downvote: this question should be closed, not downvoted. In any case: this question is good, but off-topic here (not about programming, but about using computers). You should ask to our sister site: superuser (see https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) for all sister sites.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I do disagree about both downvoting and closing. There is an arbitrary large number of cases where encoding matters in programming, and this could easily be a problem one encounters everyday in programming.
E.g. writing an Outlook Macro that could be annoyed by the weird encoding.

Comment: Yes, but in the other site is more useful. Do not assume that programmers never go in superuser, unix, security, serverfault, etc. We use all sites for relevant information. Superuser is often used for macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because Microsoft for some reason thought that they should convert the smily symbols `:)` or `:-)` to `J` using a font-face called as `Wingdings`. Therefore whenever you receive that email on a device that doesn't have that font installed it just shows a `J`. Usually the wingdings font face is available on most Mac and Windows operating systems, but not on devices smartphones and tablets. So, if a smartphone email app doesn't include the Wingdings font and they receive an email from MS Outlook they just get a `J` instead of `:)`

The reason outlook shows a `J` in the email preview is basically the same, it just isn't able to use the Wingdings font there.

You can read about the Wingdings font here: [Wingdings Font](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/wingdings)